# logging in using websecurity only works on localhost

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

```
//custom authorization
public class RedirectAuthorize : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        if (!filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
                filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new
                RouteValueDictionary(new { controller = "NotExist" }));            
        }
    }
}

[RedirectAuthorize]
public class SystemController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {   
        return View();
    }
}

// this method is inside AccountController
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(User acc)
{
    if(ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        if(WebSecurity.Login(acc.username, acc.password))
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "System");
    }

    ModelState.AddModelError("IncorrectDetails", "Wrong details. Please try again.");
        return View(acc);
    }
}
```

When this code is run locally on my PC it works perfectly. I can log in  and log out without problems, and I can't access the SystemController when I'm logged out. Exactly what I want.

But when I publish the site on my domain, I can't log in for some reason. It asks me for credentials inside a window:

[image: Window]

I don't understand why this pop-up comes first of all, and second of all I just want the user to log-in with the regular `<input type="text">` fields.

The public version has the exact same tables and data inside the database. Nothing seems wrong with that.

**Edit:**

Could it be because I'm not using SSL on my host?

**Edit2:**

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
   <forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>
```

Did the trick. Apparently you have to set the auth mode :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you have either Basic or Windows Authentication enabled on the server.  Both pop up that dialog.  You want only forms authentication and anonymous.

Comment: How could I disable Basic / Windows authentication? Sorry, I'm not familiar with these. I'll do some research. My website works with forms authentication.

Comment: @user1534664 - You have to configure IIS on your server.  Since You haven't told us anything about where you're hosting your site, it's hard for us to tell you how that's done.

Comment: Its ok dude, you helped me on the right path :) I figured it out!